# One million dollar in cash once or the ability to always draw a 5 dollar note out of your pocket (infinite times)?

Tags: cash

What would you pick?

Note: If you want to get 5000 bucks out of your pocket, you need to draw 1000 times...

Comment: So I can collect money for bigger purchases?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's hypothetical.

Comment: $1M will allow you to withdraw $40,000/yr long term. (4% withdrawal rule) - that's only $110/day. It requires 22 pocket dips.

Comment: Guys, the help center is not saying anything about hypothetical questions.
"...Strategies for saving more money..."

Comment: lol, is the $5 tax free?

Comment: Good question. Any tax consultant around?

Comment: @AndreasDaoutis although you can ask hypotheticals, it has to be something that other people can imagine is related to you. Without further context this is too farfetched to be considered on topic. So feel free to edit it

Comment: In the "don't ask" section, listed: *"you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can pull $5 every time you reach into your pocket and you assume that it takes approximately 2 seconds to reach in and pull out then I would take the infinite money.

Rationale:
Assuming 8 hours for sleeping per day and 3 hours for personal hygiene and eating that leaves us with 13 hours a day for pulling.

Every Min
 $150.00

Every Hour
 $9,000.00

Every Day
 $117,000.00

Every Week
 $819,000.00

Every Year
 $42,588,000.00

Clearly one years work is way more beneficial. Even after taxes you are a multi millionaire.

Comment: Think about the damage you create to the back side of your hand or the pocket by pulling 1,000,000 times...

Comment: Yeah but think about how jacked your arm would be from pulling all day :-D

Comment: By the way, do I need to pay tax for money coming out of my pocket? :D

Comment: I was going to ask if you had a magical pocket that produced money if you needed to pay taxes on it lol. I don't know what tax code that's covered under. I also wanted to know if you could use two hands instead of one but I figured what we had was enough for a basic answer lol

Comment: No you are not allowed to use your second hand

Comment: Illegal income is taxable so I imagine magical income would also be taxable.

Comment: @stannius - but the current tax rate on magical income is magical. So ipso fatso there's always that...